# App name expiry with non approved app

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore-approval

My app was rejected by the review team. It is however getting close to expiry (119 days). I will not be able to make the required changes in time - is it even necessary to have the app approved within 120 days? Or is uploading the binary enough for the expiry clock to stop ticking?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I found in Apple's doc:

> Once you have created your app, and it is in the state Prepare  For
>   Upload or Waiting For Upload, you will have 120 days (4 months) from
>   your creation date in iTunes Connect, to deliver a binary to Apple. 
>   If you do not deliver a binary before the 120-day deadline, your app
>   will be deleted from iTunes Connect. As a result of this deletion,
>   your  app name will be able to be used by another developer and you
>   cannot reuse the app name, SKU or Bundle ID. See the Deleting an App
>   section of this guide to learn more about the ramifications of App
>   Delete.

So I guess it is sufficient to upload the binary within time...

Answer (score 1):

iTunes App Name reservations no longer expire.

http://blog.salsitasoft.com/apples-new-app-name-reservation-policy/

I lost one of my app before and I can't take its name again. But now I have too many apps that are waiting in iTunes Connect about 1 year. * update 10+ years